# Simple PHP contact form returning blank results?

Tags: php

I have a very basic form. The form is being sent to the email, however it does not return any data, not sure what I am missing.

Here is my HTML code...

```
<form id="contact" action="process.php" />

    <label for="name">Your name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required>

    <label for="size">Your Size</label>
    <select id="size" name="size" required>
        <option value="">Choose a Size</option>
        <option value="s">S</option>
        <option value="m">M </option>
        <option value="l">L</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 

</form>
```

...and here is my process.php file...

```
<?php
// Get Data 
$name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
$size = strip_tags($_POST['size']);

// Send Message
mail( "test@testing.com", "Email Contact",
"Name: $name\nSize: $size\n",
"From: Test Server" );
?>
```

This email will be received successfully, but will look like this...

Name:

Size:

It returns the labels but not the fields. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Be sure to specify that your form should be POSTed, to ensure that variables are available through `$_POST`:

```
<form id="contact" action="process.php" method="POST"/>
```

Comment: dangit you beat me! +1

Comment: do people sit on here hitting F5 over and over... crap its like I see 'new question' so I hit F5 and its already answered

Comment: ahhh of course!! I was wrecking my brain trying to see what I had missed, thanks will make as right answer

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
<form id="contact" action="process.php" method="post" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you do not define form's sending method it is assumed as `GET` as default.

Use `method="POST"`

```
<form id="contact" action="process.php" method="post">
...
</form>
```

In addition to this, you must check first if form is posted:

```
if(isset($_POST)) {
    $name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
    $size = strip_tags($_POST['size']);

    // Send Message
    mail( "test@testing.com", "Email Contact", "Name: $name\nSize: $size\n", "From: Test Server" );
}
```

You may also use `$_REQUEST` but it is more vulnerable than `$_POST`. Because `$_REQUEST` does not mind how data comes; accepts data both from `$_GET` and `$_POST`.